# Using bs4 with python to parse a file, how do I get the text from an anchor tag?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Generic Title</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<a href="facebook.com">Face book</a>
<a href="google.com">Google</a>
</HTML>
```

how would I get the Face book and Google text from the anchor tag with bs4, every time I use `soup.find_all('a').text` it returns an attribute error
this is the code I used

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open ('basic.html', 'r') as f:
    contents = f.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(contents, "html.parser")
    
    l = soup.find_all('a').text
    print(l)
```

Comment: Hi welcome to StackOverflow. Please show your code and what you have tried that doesn't work. See here for more information on how to ask a question with a sufficient amount of detail and clarity: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: See here for details: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting, and also here https://stackoverflow.com/markdown for understanding how markdown works, but the simple thing is to press the code blocks button, which looks like `{}` on the toolbar for the question input form.

Comment: Is this more sufficient?

Comment: Yes that's much better. In your code you have a line to get all the a tags with `l = find_all('a').text` but that is incorrect really. `find_all()` returns a list of tags, not a single tag. So then you have to iterate that list to deal with each a tag one by one (if the list is not empty)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to iterate the `ResultSet` that is created by `find_all()` and call `.text` on each element:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html='''
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Generic Title</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<a href="facebook.com">Facebook</a>
<a href="google.com">Google</a>
</HTML>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

for tag in soup.find_all('a'):
    print(tag.text)
```

##### Example based on your code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open ('basic.html', 'r') as f:
    contents = f.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(contents, "html.parser")

for l in soup.find_all('a'):
    print(l.text)
```